# In Ruby how do you round down a number to 2 significant digits

Tags: ruby, rounding

For example,

If I have 24987654, I need it to return 24000000, is this possible?

Comment: Sure, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one naive algorithm :

```
n = 24987654
n / (10 ** (n.to_s.size - 2)) * (10 ** (n.to_s.size - 2)
=> 24000000
```

Comment: you probably meant `n.to_s.size` instead of `n.size`

Comment: I'm using MRI 2.0.0, let me check with 1.9.3

Comment: Ok, on my machine (64 bits), integers size is 8 bytes, didn't bother to check with another integer that the one provided in the example, that is 8 characters long, nice coincidence, I guess you're on a 32 bits machine. I thought Fixnum#size will return the number of chars, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it:

```
x -= x % (10 ** (Math.log(x, 10).to_i - 1))
```

In the above statement:

1. `Math.log(x, 10).to_i - 1` determines the number of insignificant digits to remove
2. `x % (10 ** number_of_insignificant_digits)` computes the insignificant part of the number
3. subtract the value from step 2 from the initial number and now `x` contains the result

Here's an online test for the program: http://ideone.com/trSNOr

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 24987654
n.round((n.to_s.size - 2)*-1) #=> 25000000
n.ceil((n.to_s.size - 2)*-1) #=> 25000000
n.floor((n.to_s.size - 2)*-1) #=> 24000000

n = 24187654
n.round((n.to_s.size - 2)*-1) #=> 24000000
n.ceil((n.to_s.size - 2)*-1) #=> 25000000
n.floor((n.to_s.size - 2)*-1) #=> 24000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way:

```
n = 24987654
a = n.to_s[0, 2] + '0' * ((a.to_s.length)-2)
```

Will output the string:

```
=> "24000000"
```

You can convert it as integer calling the `.to_i` method